# Uninstall IE8 from XP SP3 Install?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer-8, windows-xp, internet-explorer-6

So I'm trying to run some virtual machines for testing different websites, and the only version of Windows I have is XP SP3, which for some reason comes preinstalled with IE8. I'm wanting to uninstall IE8 and install IE6 on one install and IE7 on another. However, searching the internet there seems to be only two methods listed: Add/Remove Programs (it's not there) and navigating to Windows/ie8/ and running some spunint.exe file. As far as the second method goes, this install does not appear to have a Windows/ie8 directory. So, is there any way I can get rid of the IE8 that's already installed, or am I going to be forced to download Microsoft's trial XP which works for crap on my VM software? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply use the Microsoft-provided [Virtual Machine Images](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkID=70868).

Comment: I've used them in the past, and I'm trying to avoid this, mainly because they expire, and it's a real pain to reinstall every few months. Not to mention, from my experience you're forced to crack them as they require an activation code since for some reason upon install they think you've changed out all your hardware. This is why I'm trying to avoid them.

Comment: Coming back to this later, this is definitely the correct answer, especially after finding ievms: https://github.com/xdissent/ievms

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, if you installed IE8 before SP3, SP3 seals it in. Microsoft announced that on their blog here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ie/ie-and-windows-xp-service-pack-3

The blog post refers to the beta or IE8, but is still applicable to the final release. The work around is to remove SP3, then remove IE8, then re-install SP3.

Comment: This is actually an install of SP3, so there's no real way to remove it as far as I can tell..i.e. you get SP3 out of the box.

Comment: I think then you are stuck with IE8, and might need to use a Virtual Machine Image as Joey suggested. There are other hacks lying around to get IE 6 working side-by-side with IE8, such as MultipleIE.

Comment: Yeah, I've used the multiple IE hack and along with the standalone IE7 to do this before, but it seems like that messes with the functionality of each browser, and makes me worry about the accuracy of testing in such an environment. It's starting to look like it's my only option though =\

Comment: Another odd-ball idea might be to get a hold of a Windows XP RTM or SP2 disk, re-install your operating system clean and ensure IE 8 never ends up on there.

Comment: I'm going with the Multiple IEs / Standalone IE7 workaround, as of the available options, it seems like the best I can do.